# Magento 2 Payflow pro Currency issue

Tags: magento2, paypal-payflow-pro

I have recently migrated a site to Magento 2.

There i getting a strange issue with payment method.

I am using **Payflow pro** on website credit card payment method. Our store default currency is **CAD** and allowed currency is also **CAD** but when payment process it showing in **USD** in paypal manager.

I have tried to add currency directly in function this `postRequest` in file `Magento\Paypal\Model\Payflow\Service\Gateway` but no luck.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you solved your issue?

Comment: Yes its resolved

Comment: Can you please share the solution?

Comment: Ok solution is bad but it works which currency you are using

Comment: I am using the Canadian Dollar.

Comment: `if (!array_key_exists('currency',$request->getData())) {
   $request->setData('currency','CAD');
  }`

Comment: add this code in `vendor\Magento\Paypal\Model\Payflow\Service\Gateway.php` after line 86  i.e after `$client->setConfig($clientConfig);`  it

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here.

Never change core files!
Magento 2 core are vendors and managed by composer. Any Magento update will override your custom changes.

I fixed this issue using a custom module with a Plugin that will override the Magento\Paypal\Model\Payflowpro::buildBasicRequest method